# Combining double class selectors with :last-child

Tags: javascript, html, css

My intent here is to select the last element that has both the `message` and `theirs` classes and a `data-msgid` attribute:

```js
var theirLastMessage = document.querySelector('#container .message.theirs[data-msgid]:last-child');
console.log(theirLastMessage);
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="message mine" data-msgid="1"></div>
  <div class="message theirs" data-msgid="2"></div>
  <div class="message mine" data-msgid="3"></div>
  <div class="message theirs" data-msgid="4"></div>
  <div class="message mine" data-msgid="5"></div>
</div>
```

However, `querySelector` is returning *null*, when I want it to be returning the `div` with `data-msgid=4` in this example. Why doesn't this work and how can I get the element I'm looking for?

I'm not sure if my post title is accurate, I don't have my head wrapped around the problem.

Comment: There *is* no `:last-child` with both of those classes on.

Comment: @jonrsharpe  ... `<div class="message theirs" data-msgid="4"></div>` is the last child with both of those classes isn't it?

Comment: You have misunderstood what `:last-child` does, it only matches the *actual last child of the parent*, `<div class="message mine" data-msgid="5"></div>`. If you want to get the last *of your selected subset*, try `querySelectorAll` and then getting the `.length - 1`th element from it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh. That's... annoying. All right, thanks. If there's a huge number of matching elements should I expect a performance hit? (Haven't tested yet)

Comment: @jonrsharpe The answers there are disappointing but yeah close enough; thanks.

Comment: I was going to answer what John said. Your best approach is to use this, I guess. Otherwise, if you're using jQuery, that has a built-in .last() method: `theirs = document.querySelectorAll('#container .message.theirs[data-msgid]');
console.log(theirs[theirs.length - 1]);`